When comparing timeseries data I getting an error in if statement "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"
I need to add a function to deal with the NA values, but I am comparing one temperature to another to see the difference between them and I don't know how best to deal with the NAs. I would like for the program to ignore the NAs, and just compare the temperature to the next available one.
Here is the code I am using (this is part of a large four loop with additional fucntions)
for(i in 2:nrow(cow_1)) {
    if(abs(cow_1$temperature..C[i] - cow_1$temperature..C[i-1]) > 1) {
      meanval=avg6(cow_1$temperature..C,i)
      cow_1$temperature..C = next12(cow_1$temperature..C,i,meanval)
    }
  }


When asking a question related to code, the very first tag you should add is for the language that you're using, so that your question gets in front of the people who may be able to help you. Please [edit] your post to add that tag. Also, your experiences at SO will be much better if you take the time to complete the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works.
